# How do you upgrade MAMP's PHP to PHP 5.3 ?

Tags: upgrade, mamp, php-5.3, libjpeg

I haven't been able to find any resources on how to do this.. Anyone have any ideas or resources?!

I've tried changing the ./configure options and I'm solving things one at a time but it seems like this method could take forever.. My current error is..

checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... no
configure: error: Problem with libjpeg.(a|so). Please check config.log for more information.

I'm running Snow Leopard.

Any help would be great,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version (1.9) of MAMP / MAMP PRO includes PHP 5.3 and is available on the [MAMP download page](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question- but still relevant.

I'm updating my MAMP and am keeping up to date on [PHP's stable releases](https://www.php.net/downloads.php) by  using a guide I found at [davidgolding.net](http://www.davidgolding.net/cakephp/upgrading-php-in-mamp.html)

## **The Guide goes as follows:**

First, run the

```
phpinfo()
```

function in a PHP script on your localhost or go to PHPMyAdmin and hunt down the configuration page. You should see a large chunk of configuration markup at or near the top:

```
'./configure' '--with-mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library' 
'--with-apxs2=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs' 
'--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library'
'--with-png-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-zlib' 
'--with-freetype-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' 
'--prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5' '--exec-prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5' 
'--sysconfdir=/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5' '--with-soap' 
'--with-config-file-path=/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5'
'--enable-track-vars' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' 
'--with-bz2=/usr' '--with-ldap' '--with-mysqli=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config' 
'--with-sqlite' '--with-ttf' '--with-t1lib=/Applications/MAMP/Library' 
'--enable-mbstring=all' '--with-curl=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--enable-dbx' 
'--enable-sockets' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-imap=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/imap-2006i' 
'--enable-soap' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-calendar' 
'--with-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg' '--enable-dbase' 
'--enable-exif' '--with-libxml-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' 
'--with-gettext=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-xsl=/Applications/MAMP/Library' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg' 
'--with-mcrypt=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-openssl'
```

Copy and paste this whole chunk into your text editor and **remove the single quotes** (search and replace should do it). Look for the flag

```
--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library
```

and replace it with:

```
--with-pdo-mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library
```

If you don’t do this, you might end up with an error.

```
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

Finally, add the following flag to the end:

```
--without-iconv
```

After you have downloaded the latest PHP release of your choosing from PHP Sources Snapshots,

```
cd
```

to the downloaded directory in Terminal. Paste your reformatted configuration string (all of it, including the beginning *./configure* command) and run it.

After the configuration phase is finished, run:

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Relaunch MAMP, and you’re good to go.

Comment: I tried following this instructions.  When running the `./configure ...` command, I received this error: `cannot open /Applications/MAMP/Library/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs line 217.`  Do you know how I can resolve this error?

Comment: davidgolding.net  not available

Comment: Being that this is a couple of years old, both PHP and MAMP are like likely to have changed a lot since then, it should not be assumed to work with current MAMP or PHP.

Answer (score 4):

This is bound to cause a lot of headaches. The simplest solution is to navigate over to the mamp website and grab the latest version of the application. Download it, hit the install button and you will find your php version has been updated to the latest version...

Hope this helps, I spent quite a bit of time fiddling about with upgrading PHP before I actually looked :S

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if MAMP has changed its configuration in the last few years but none of the solutions here helped me. What I did, and what worked right away was:

1. [Download the PHP version you want from MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/)
2. Unzip it and move the new PHP folder into the MAMP/bin/php folder where you will see other subfolders with names like php5.3.7
3. Restart MAMP
4. Go to the PHP panel under Server in MAMP and choose the new verion of PHP from the drop menu
5. Start MAMP.

Comment: If it only were that simple, mate :) Turns out re-installing from the website is the best option so far…

Answer (score 1):

reinstall whole MAMP is very safe. You dont even need to take a copy of old MAMP. the new install does it on its own. just feel free to download new MAMP and click install. only care u need to take is this

Edit httpd.conf and open up line to include vhosts.conf and copy old vhosts.conf from old MAMP folder.

Answer (score 0):

Goto [MAMP Download page](http://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/index.html) 
then choose
an update from the Heading
"Additional PHP versions for MAMP PRO 2.2"