# Updating MAMP to PHP 5.4.8

Tags: php, mamp

I used this guide [How do you upgrade MAMP's PHP to PHP 5.3 ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746719/how-do-you-upgrade-mamps-php-to-php-5-3) to update my PHP-Version on MAMP but it does not work.

I'm not sure if I did everything right.
I downloaded php 5.4.8 und put the folder into MAMP -> conf and renamed it to php5.4.8 to make it even with the other PHP Folders in there. Than I followed the guide, but got the following error:

```
Binarys-MacBook-Air:~ BinaryCoder$ cd /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.4.8 
Binarys-MacBook-Air:php5.4.8 BinaryCoder$ ./configure --with-mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-apxs2=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs --with-gd --with-jpeg-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-png-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-zlib --with-freetype-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4 --exec-prefix=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4 --sysconfdir=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf --with-config-file-path=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/conf --enable-ftp --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-bz2=/usr --with-ldap --with-mysqli=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config --with-t1lib=/Applications/MAMP/Library --enable-mbstring=all --with-curl=/Applications/MAMP/Library --enable-sockets --enable-bcmath --with-imap=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/imap-2007f --enable-soap --with-kerberos --enable-calendar --with-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg --enable-exif --with-libxml-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-gettext=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-xsl=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-pdo-mysql=/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg --with-mcrypt=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library --with-openssl --enable-zip --with-iconv=/Applications/MAMP/Library --without-iconv
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking whether to enable runpaths... yes
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking for bison... bison -y
checking for bison version... 2.3 (ok)
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking whether to enable computed goto gcc extension with re2c... no
checking whether cc supports -no-cpp-precomp... yes
checking whether to force non-PIC code in shared modules... no
checking whether /dev/urandom exists... yes
checking for pthreads_cflags... 
checking for pthreads_lib... 

Configuring SAPI modules
checking for AOLserver support... no
checking for Apache 1.x module support via DSO through APXS... no
checking for Apache 1.x module support... no
checking whether to enable Apache charset compatibility option... no
checking for Apache 2.0 filter-module support via DSO through APXS... no
checking for Apache 2.0 handler-module support via DSO through APXS... 

Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs follows:
cannot open /Applications/MAMP/Library/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apxs line 217.
configure: error: Aborting
Binarys-MacBook-Air:php5.4.8 BinaryCoder$
```

What was my misstake?
Thank you!

Comment: try putting it on Server Fault. There's even a similar question there.

Comment: Have you tried to install it via homebrew? It is quite easy, actually and you can include it in your MAMP (or complete the installation by custom Apache and MySQL installations)

Comment: Reopening; MAMP is primarily a development setup - as such, it is perfectly appropriate to ask/answer questions on it here (Server Fault is not particularly fond of these, although some answers can be found there as well).

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed? It comes with alot commonly used C header files which are missing from vanilla os-x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP only supports the following
Programs and libraries:

- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.22
- PHP 5.2.17
- PHP 5.3.14 (MAMP PRO only)
- PHP 5.4.4
- MySQL 5.5.25
- phpMyAdmin 3.5.1
- SQLiteManager 1.2.4
- Alternative PHP Cache (APC) 3.1.9
- curl 7.24.0
- eAccelerator 0.9.6.1
- Expat XML Parser 2.0.1
- FreeType 2.4.8
- gettext 0.18.1.1
- jpeg 8d
- libiconv 1.14
- Libidn 1.17
- libmcrypt 2.6.8
- libpng 1.5.7
- libxml2 2.7.8
- libxslt 1.1.26
- Sablotron XML processor 1.0.3
- t1lib 5.1.2
- XCache 1.2.2
- XCache 1.3.2
- Xdebug 2.2.0
- PHP/YAZ 1.0.14
- YAZ 4.0.1

This update is already available on  download page, here php 5.4.8 is not available